# Minimumaj paroj inter afrikato kaj plosivo+frikativo

Tags: pronunciation

Ĉu ekzistas minimumaj paroj en Esperanto, kiuj distingigas la sonajn parojn c/ts, ĉ/tŝ, kaj ĝ/dĵ?

Minimuma paro por du sonoj estas paro da vortoj, kies sola diferenco inter si estas tiuj du sonoj. Ekzemple, minimuma paro por c/ĉ estas caro/ĉaro.

Prefere mi havu senchavajn parojn, kiuj ne estas obscenaj. (Do ekzemple *ne* katsemo/kacemo, kiu estas ja minimuma paro tamen maldeca.) Kunmetaĵoj kaj afiksoj estas tute en ordo.

---

Mi ŝatus scii tion, por ke mi povu pli facile per ekzemplo klarigi al homoj, ke la sonoj c kaj ts ktp estas malsamaj. Mi *neniel* volas diri, ke la literoj c, ĉ, kaj ĝ ne estas bezonataj!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mi provis trovi kiel eble plej senchavajn minimumajn parojn. Jen la rezultoj de mia serĉado:

dĵ/ĝ:

- pred·ĵet·o / preĝ·et·o
- vend·ĵet·o / venĝ·et·o

tŝ/ĉ:

- pint·ŝat·a / pinĉ·at·a
- sort·ŝat·a / sorĉ·at·a

ts/c:

- koment·sem·a / komenc·em·a
- plat·sem·a / plac·em·a

Notu, ke malgraŭ la supraĵa simileco inter "koment·sem·a" kaj "plat·sem·a", ili fakte estas tute malsamspecaj kunmetaĵoj: "koment·sem·a" signifas "semanta komentojn" (kun metafora interpreto de "semi"), dum "plat·sem·a" signifas "karakterizita de plata(j) semo(j)".

Answer (score 2):

We can certainly build new (and somewhat nonsensical) words that make up such pairs:

## ĉ/ts

- kaĉ·al·o (mush-like thing) / kat·ŝal·o (cat shawl)
- kaĉ·ik·a (science of mush) / kat·ŝik·a (cat-chique)
- kaĉ·il·o (mush(ing) tool) / kat·ŝil·o (cat chyle)

I've constructed these like so:

1. find a (non-obscene) stem pair, like *kaĉ*/*kat*, that either ends in a africative and matching plosive or begins with an africative and matching fricative.
2. *kaĉ* has the africative *ĉ* at the end. Thus prepend the fricative *ŝ* "missing" in *kat* to all Esperanto word building suffixes in turn and see which ones become existing stems by that (e.g. *ik*/*ŝik*).

   (I haven't yet tried with stem pairs that begin with the africative/fricative, but there you'd have to append the matching plosive to Esperanto word building prefixes and/or stems to see if that results in a new stem.)
3. For those that do, append the suffix (e.g. *ik*) to the stem with the africative (*kaĉ*), and append the new stem starting with the fricative (*ŝik*) to the stem with the plosive (*kat*)

   (Had we started with a stem pair that begin with the africative/fricative, we'd have to *pre*pend the matching stuff from this step, of course.)
4. find the word terminator (word-type indicator) that "best" matches both results, and append it to both

I've done this semi-manually using a paper dictionary and http://www.simplavortaro.org/, but given comprehensive lists of stems, prefixes and suffixes, it should be possible to fully automate this search. (And maybe some more meaningful constructed words would be among the pairs found that way.)