# Ĉu DZ estas fonemo?

Tags: pronunciation

Mi jam vidis iujn aserti ke la literkombino DZ estas fonemo, sed aliaj diras, ke ne. La argumento por estas ke ĝi ofte prononciĝas kiel afrikato, kiel en "edzo", kiu plej ofte prononĉigas e-dzo anstataŭ ed-zo.

Sed, kontraŭe, ni ja havas vortojn kun la kombino DS en iom neoftaj lokoj... *Feldspato, handspeko*, kaj tiel plu, sed se DZ estas fonemo, ĉu oni ne havus DZ tie: * *feldzpato, handzpeko*?

Comment: Mi konkludis, ke jes, sed se iu havas kontraŭan pruvon, mi ŝatus vidi. Mia konkludo estas ke iuj kombinaĵoj, precipe ds, ts kaj kz pruvas ke Esperanto estas nur preskaŭ-fonetika. Ili plej ofte legiĝas dz, c kaj gz; ne diru al mi ke la kz en ekzemplo, en la praktiko, diferas de la gz de zigzago; aŭ ke feldspato ne havas /dz/, aŭ ke Pitsburgo ne estas prononcata Picburgo (alia ortografio valida). Mi tamen ne proponas ke ni skribu tsunamo por cunamo; la Rusa skribas цунами sed Питтсбург. Do oni akceptu ke E'o ne perfektas, sed la sistemo ja sufiĉe bonas.

Answer (score 2):

Por paroli pri tio, ĉu la literkombinaĵo *dz* estas fonemo, oni devas paroli pri distingigo de afrikato disde plosivo+frikativo; ekzemple *c* disde *ts*. En la internacia fonetika alfabeto ni skribas /t͡s/ por la sono de *c*, dum /ts/ por la *du* sonoj de *ts*. Ĉar ni ne havas apartan literon por /d͡z/ ni triviale ne povas distingigi ĝin disde /dz/. Do, laŭ mi, /d͡z/ ne estas fonemo en Esperanto. Ke multaj homoj prononcus /dz/ kiel /d͡z/ ne signifas, ke /d͡z/ estas aparta fonemo; /d͡z/ nur estas alofono de /dz/. Mi ofte ne kunfandas /dz/ al /d͡z/ en *edzo*, dum ekzemple mi ja dirus /d͡z/ en *frandzi*.

Cetere, /t͡s/ ja estas fonemo, ĉar ni povas distingigi ĝin disde /ts/, kaj [ekzistas minimumaj paroj inter /t͡s/ kaj /ts/](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5243/25).

Comment: Mi ne scias, ĉu inter DZ kaj D-Z estas minimumaj paroj. Sed tio demandigis min, kiel prononciĝas la DS en ekz. feldspato, kiel mi antaŭe diris. /ldsp/ kun /ds/ estas stranga prononci. Same por la TS en Montserato, ĉu mi rajtas diri c?

Comment: Ne _povas_ ekzisti minimumaj paroj inter /d͡z/ kaj /dz/, ĉar ni ne havas apartan literon por tio. Se oni skribas ⟨dz⟩ en vorto laŭ mi oni povas laŭplaĉe prononci tion kiel /d͡z/ aŭ /dz/; la du sonojn ni ne distingigas, nek distingas. Oni prononcu _feldspato_ prefere per plena /d/ kaj /s/. Prefere ⟨ts⟩ restu /ts/ ne /t͡s/, sed kiel vi diris, se oni skribas _Pitsburgo_ estas tre malfacile en flua parolado vere diri /pitsˈburɡ.ɔ/ anstataŭ /pit͡sˈburɡ.ɔ/. Tamen en Montserato oni facile povas enmeti etan paŭzon inter ⟨t⟩ kaj ⟨s⟩, ĉar tie estas natura loko por disigi silabojn: /mɔnt.səˈra.tɔ/.

Comment: feldspato mi povas prononci kaj akcepti, mi eĉ preferas ĝin al mia artefarita "feldzpato", sed mi preferas enkonduki formon kun dz, kiam estas ĉio ene de unu radiko; landskneĥto < landzkneĥto, sed feldspato venas origine de feld-spato, do DS pli bonas. Same mi skribas Picburgo, sed Montserato.

Comment: Mi precipe konsentas kun vi. Ja _feldspato_ estas pli bona pro la etimologio, kaj ankaŭ mi preferas _Picburgo_ kaj _Montserato_. Mi ne certas pri _landskneĥto_. Unuflanke, origine en la germana estis _lantknecht_ kaj poste _landsknecht_, kie ⟨ds⟩ oni prononcas kiel ⟨ts⟩. Oni tiam devus konscii, ke la _s_ estas nur elemento por kombini du radikojn; _landsknecht_ estas kunmetaĵo de _land_ kaj _knecht_, do eble _landkneĥto_ estus pli bona elekto. Pro la _k_ por mi fakte estas pli facile prononci _landskneĥto_ ol _landzkneĥto_, ĉar ĉi tie _k_ estas la sola senvoĉa konsonanto el la kvin sinsekvaj.

Comment: oni povus eĉ paŭsi "landservanto"

Comment: Ĝuste. Eble tamen la vorto _landskneĥto_ estis elektita pro historiaj kialoj; emfazi, ke temas pri specifa speco de soldato.